# How to handle the rotation of mpmovie player object in iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I'm using a custom movie player in my application, its working fine.

But I'm stuck up with managing the rotation of the player, I want to rotate the player as the phone rotates, similar to the default nature of mpmovie player.

How can I control that?

Comment: Are you using `MPMoviePlayer` inside of your own view, or `MPMoviePlayerViewController`?

Answer (score 0):

Do the view controllers in the hierarchy above it support auto-rotation?  By default, only portrait orientation is supported, but you can override `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` to specify others.

Comment: Yes, I have passed as return YES in shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method for each view but still it responding with portrait only